# How to get the value of the document title in latex?

Tags: latex

I am wondering how I can get the document title in LaTex, for use elsewhere in the document. I just want to be able to echo it.

Comment: I'm sure there's a way of having the header of every page have the title in it. With fancyhdr or the memoir document class. So those files will contain an answer. I don't know enough to extract the info though... (I just searched fancyhdr.sty for "title" and got no hits, though...)

Comment: How is this not a real question? The answer is `\makeatletter \@title \makeatother`.

Comment: Indeed. If there's any problem with this question it's that it should be moved to the tex stack exchange site.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Using `\@title` does not work because `\maketitle` clears `\@title`. This seems silly to me but that's the way it is. One solution is to redefine `\title` to save the title somewhere else. For instance,

```
\def\title#1{\gdef\@title{#1}\gdef\THETITLE{#1}}
```

then use `\THETITLE`.

You can do the other way around: `\def\MYTITLE{...}` then `\title{\MYTITLE}` and later use `\MYTITLE` again.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick, although I had to enclose the define in `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`, which starts to be a whole lot of effort. So since I only need to use the title one other time, there's not much point. It'd be nice if there were a more sensible solution.

Comment: This should be in tex.stackexchange.com.  This didn't work for me.  I needed to use `\title{My Title}
\makeatletter
\let\thetitle\@title
\makeatother`
And then use `\thetitle` later in the text.

Answer (score 23):

I had success just writing a new command.

```
\newcommand{\mytitle}{...}

\title{\mytitle}
```

Answer (score 7):

There is a package called `authoraftertitle` that does exactly this

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{authoraftertitle}
\setlength\parindent{0 pt}

\begin{document}

\title{a good title}
\author{a better author}
\date{the best date}

\maketitle

the title is: \textbf{\MyTitle} \\
the author is: \textbf{\MyAuthor} \\
the data is: \textbf{\MyDate} \\

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a workaround...

```
\let\titleoriginal\title           % save original \title macro
\renewcommand{\title}[1]{          % substitute for a new \title
    \titleoriginal{#1}%               % define the real title
    \newcommand{\thetitle}{#1}        % define \thetitle
}

\title{This is my title}

\begin{document}
\thetitle
\end{document}
```

The short version of the title was ignored here...